# Run onLoad script when page refreshed with AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a piece of jQuery for making items draggable:

```
$( ".draggable" ).draggable();});
```

Works fine [here](http://francesca-designed.me/create-a-status/index.php), you can drag the words around

It works by running the script which adds some classnames to any span with `class="draggable"` and it does this on page load, so they look like this:

```
<span class="draggable ui-draggable" style="position: relative; left: -129.625px; top: -137.625px;">confident</span>
```

This issue is that pressing the green button refreshes the wordbank with AJAX, it calls in a new file, wordbank.php and every time you press it'll generate a fresh pool of words for you.

But because of that, once you've refreshed the AJAX it doesn't run the script again so the dragging doesn't work.

How can I get the script to rerun with AJAX?

Comment: i'm not sure i'm understand what you need but you can attach a function that can run the script again after the load has finished. just use the callback function in the ajax call.

Comment: The line of code at the top of this post doesn't affect anything loaded after it. So when you refresh the wordbank with the AJAX call, it doesn't run the script on it. Could you please explain this answer in a proper answer as if it's correct I can't mark it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By inspecting the newly created elements you can see that they are missing the `ui-draggable` class. You need to call `$( ".draggable" ).draggable();` again to bind the new/dynamic elements.

I think the best way to do this is in the `success` or `complete` callback of your AJAX request, you can use this line:

`$('.draggable:not(.ui-draggable)').draggable();`

to bind any words that are new and DON'T already have the `ui-draggable` class.

Since you're already using jquery you should take advantage of their ajax method:

```
function refreshWords()
{
     $.ajax({
        url: "wordbank.php",
        success: function(data){
            $("#wordbank").html(data);
            $('.draggable:not(.ui-draggable)').draggable();      
        }
     });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try using:

```
$('#yourDivId').load("yourPhpUrl.php",function(){
      //the code you want to run after the ajax was completed running   
      $( ".draggable" ).draggable();
});
```